# Create View That Executes Data From a SQL Table Every 10 Minutes

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to write a SQL (not Oracle) table that shows the utilization of devices. I scripted SQL for the information but I want to automate it.

What I want is, let's say this is for my query result.

```
Column A         Column B         Column C
Device_Name     Utilization       12:00 AM
```

I want this SQL to execute itself every 10 minutes and write the result as "insert into view" to the view (or another SQL table if easier) I will create such as:

```
Column A         Column B         Column C
Device_Name     Utilization       12:00 AM
Device_Name     Utilization       12:10 AM
Device_Name     Utilization       12:20 AM
```

I have heard about something like WAITFOR() as if I put it inside a while loop it will execute itself regularly. But I  couldn't figure out the "insert" algorithm as most insert commands were used for certain values.

So my question is:

1. is it possible to do this in SQL?
2. is it really convenient/effective as will it lag the database? because the loop will be running for a month and this is equal to almost 45000 rows at the end. what are the practises of optimizing it i.e. `with(nolock)`

UPDATE:
Unfortunately I use the account that my company which has very strict privacy rules gave me so I don't have an authorization to use SQL Server agent. The account is not sysadmin.

Comment: First of all, please clarify DB you use, because solution for Oracle can be totally different than solution for MS SQL Server. If you need to run something every 10 minutes, the easiest way is to use any kind of scheduling software (e.g. SQL Agent in MS SQL Server)

Comment: Thank you for clarfying this that I realized I did a typo in the tags and typed mysql instead of mssql. Changed the tag now. I use MS SQL Server)

Comment: If you use SQL Server why don't you use SQL Server Agent jobs? Views are packaged queries, not executable code. You could use a stored procedure but that would only work as the client connection was open. To run something in "the background" you need SQL Server Agent which already supports scheduling

Comment: As for #2 - impossible to answer because you haven't really asked a question yet. What are you trying to do? What metrics are you trying to collect and how? There are ways to collect metrics already. `WITH (NOLOCK)` is a huge bug, not an optimization. 45K rows is no data at all. So little data can fit into a CPU's cache. Using in-memory tables and columnstore indexes allows collecting [real-time analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/get-started-with-columnstore-for-real-time-operational-analytics?view=sql-server-ver16) over millions of rows

Comment: Unfortunately the SQL account they gave me is not sysadmin so the SQL Server Agent is not available for me.

Comment: Without knowing why you want to do this, its impossible to answer this. It sounds like an x/y problem to me, whatever problem you are trying to solve can potentially be solved in a much better fashion.

Comment: Can't you ask for another account? Or tell "them" to create the job that runs your code for you

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use a view to store data. You should add a table for that.

To come back to your question to save data each x time.

What you can do is create a SQL Agent job which does the insert statement for you to the specific table.

[image]

[image]

Navigate to steps:
[image]

Create the insert script here:
[image]

And create a job schedule in the next tab:
[image]

Comment: This answer is so detailed and amazing but unfortunately the account my company gave me for SQL is not sysadmin so the sql server agent is not available to execute.

Comment: Create a stored procedure with the logic you need and create a job with Windows Scheduler to execute it? (by example with Powershell or CMD?)

Comment: I will try that now and If i proceed, I will pin that answer as accepted one and close the question. Thank you!